# discord bot ban/kick command is not working

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i made a ban and kick command but wenn i use then my bot craches with the error [ message.guild.member is not a function ]

this is my code for the ban command

```
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ban')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
        message.guild.member(user).ban('Vous avez été ban par un admin').then(() => {
          message.channel.send(`${user.username} a été ban !`);
        }
        ).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
        );
      } else {
        message.channel.send('Vous n\'avez pas la permission de ban !');
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send('Vous devez mentionner un utilisateur !');
    }
  }
});
```

this is my code for the kick command

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'kick')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
          member.kick('Vous avez été kick par un admin').then(() => {
            message.reply(`${user.tag} a été kick !`);
          }).catch(err => {
            message.reply('Je ne peux pas kick cet utilisateur !');
            console.log(err);
          });
        } else {
          message.reply('Vous n\'avez pas la permission de kick !');
        }
      } else {
        message.reply('Cet utilisateur n\'est pas dans le serveur !');
      }
    } else {
      message.reply('Vous devez mentionner un utilisateur !');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => { //since you're using v13, *message* is deprecated. So you need to change it to *messageCreate*
   if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "kick")) { //You can do ${prefix}kick too.
      if(!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) return message.reply("You can't use this command") //This line code is for when the member using this command. It will return when permissions isn't detected.
      if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) return message.reply("I can't use this command.") //This is for when the bot missing its permissions.
      const member = message.mentions.members.first(); //users is not going to work.
      if(!member) return message.reply("Who are you going to kick?") //This line code is for when the member didn't find or pinged.
      if(!member.bannable) return message.reply("I can't ban this person") // This is for the person that is not bannable.
      await member.ban({ reason: 'Your reply'}) //You need to await, so it can fetch the member.
   }
})
```

You can also use their ID to ban using

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

You can also add reason for your own using

```
const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
member.ban({
   reason: reason
})
```

And using an embed

```
const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
member.ban({
   reason: reason
})

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`${reason}`)
.setColor('RANDOM')

message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

In addition code lines, to prevent any errors, you can use `||`. For example:

```
const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ") || "No Reason" //This is to prevent any errors for your embed
```

And yes you can also use `===` for preventing an error when you accidentally pinged yourself.

```
if(!member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply("your_message");
```

You need to add this code line before the `args` line

```
 const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
```

So it should be like this

```
 const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
 const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ") || "No Reason"
```

Comment: i tryed and got the error `message is not defined`

Comment: nop sorry got it to work my ban command was bloking the start of the bot
thx for your help

Comment: but for the ban with ID i have this error `args is not defined`

Comment: got it working but my bot cant ban with the ID

Comment: and i tryed using the embed but this diden't work alos
this is the error i reciv
`DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0].description: This field is required`

Comment: got the embed working had to change it to this
`message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});`
but the reson dosent work i just get en empty embed

Comment: i added this to make the reson work
`const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
      if(!reason) return message.reply("You must provide a reason for the ban.")`
`await member.ban({reason: reason})`

but the bot dosent kollect the reson

Comment: and i addded this too make the ID work
`if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.reply("You can't ban yourself.")
      if(member.id === message.guild.owner.id) return message.reply("You can't ban the server owner.")
      if(member.id === message.guild.me.id) return message.reply("I can't ban myself.")`

Comment: Ah sorry haven't updated my answer, im at work atm

Comment: ok no wowirs im not in a ruch i can wait

Comment: If this answer gives you an idea, might leave a check as a correct answer!

Comment: so i removed
`if(!member) return message.reply("Who are you going to kick?")       if(!member.bannable) return message.reply("I can't ban this person")`

but now its just the collection of the reson thats not working

Comment: update i got the reson collection working i had to add this
`const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);`
now i only have the problem with the IDban

Comment: for the ID ban/kick command i get this error
`Cannot access 'args' before initialization`

Comment: Ah you need to add one more code line. I'll edit my answer

Comment: now i have this Cannot access 'args' before initialization

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244828/discussion-between-nemson-and-acesyyy).

Comment: i had to start a chat my code is to long

Comment: I replied on the chat

Answer (score 1):

change the permission line to this...

```js
message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)
```

change the ban line to this...

```js
user.ban({ reason:'Vous avez été ban par un admin' })
.then(() => {
    message.channel.send(`${user.username} a été ban !`);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244884/discussion-on-answer-by-gavin-discord-bot-ban-kick-command-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(user).ban()
message.guild.members.cache.get(user).kick()
```

Comment: no dident work sorry